# Change background of div when clicked/toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

Hey guys I would like to be able to add a background behind the text "CLICK ME" when clicked, so it stays active until de-clicked. I currently have a slide and toggle format which is shown here, but I have been unable to figure out where I can add another active class within the current script.

http://jsfiddle.net/schermerb/rAMQT/

```
    <div class="toggleBtn">CLICK ME</div>
    <div class="below">OH NO IM HIDDEN</div>

    <div class="toggleBtn">CLICK ME</div>
    <div class="below">OH NO IM HIDDEN</div>

    <div class="toggleBtn">CLICK ME</div>
    <div class="below">OH NO IM HIDDEN</div>

    <div class="toggleBtn">CLICK ME</div>
    <div class="below">OH NO IM HIDDEN</div>

.toggleBtn {
    font:14px noral Futura, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    margin:50px;
}
.below {
    background:red;
}

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var content = $('.below').hide();
        $('.toggleBtn').on('click', function () {
            $(this).next('.below').slideToggle();
            return false;
        });
        //register the handler to button element inside .below
        $('.below .close').on('click', function () {
            //find the ancestor .below element of the clicked button
            $(this).closest('.below').slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle an active class:

In your JS: *(note the $(this).toggleClass('active') line)*

```
$('.toggleBtn').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next('.below').slideToggle();

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
.toggleBtn.active{
    background:blue;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rAMQT/3/

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:
Add an active class to the elment the clicked.
and when the slideToggle complete remove this class;

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $('.below').hide();
    $('.toggleBtn').on('click', function () {
        var self = this;
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).next('.below').slideToggle(function(){
            $(self).removeClass("active");
        });
        return false;
    });
    //register the handler to button element inside .below
    $('.below .close').on('click', function () {
        var self = this;
        $(this).addClass("active");
        //find the ancestor .below element of the clicked button
        $(this).closest('.below').slideToggle(function(){
            $(self).removeClass("active");
        });
    });
});
```

**Css**

```
.active {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAMQT/1/)

Comment: Is there a way to keep the background active until "CLICK ME" is clicked again?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $('.below').hide();
    $('.toggleBtn').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.below').slideToggle();
        if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'active' )){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });
    //register the handler to button element inside .below
    $('.below .close').on('click', function () {
        //find the ancestor .below element of the clicked button
        $(this).closest('.below').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rAMQT/5/) with the working code

Comment: jsfiddle link was changed